# How to change image on button by click and hide the next one in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two buttons Btn1 and Btn2 with images Btn1image1.png,Btn2image1.png on them.
By clicking each button,it must show Btn1image2.png and Btn2image2.png respectively.

And also,if Btn1 is clicked Btn2 image should be the same(Btn2image1.png) and viz

How to achieve this ??

I am adding my work here,but its not working in the case of Btn2 click

```
    -(IBAction)Bt1Click:(id)sender
    {

        if (Bt1.selected=YES)
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1image2.png"];
            [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        }
        else
        {
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn2image1.png"];
            [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        [self.searchBaar resignFirstResponder];
    }

    -(IBAction)Btn2Click:(id)sender
    {
       if (Btn2.selected=YES)
       {
           UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn2image2.png"];
           [PeopButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       }
       else
       {
           UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1image1.png"];
           [PeopButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }

       [self.searchBaar resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiled...you have an assignment in your `if` condition.

Comment: this is an example of one of the perils of the dot syntax for properties :(

Comment: It will compile (with warnings) it just won't work correctly. As the warnings will, er, warn about.

Comment: hey @Nithin MK just use bellow my code and replace with your code.. try it will work with your requirement ...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call setBackgroundImage inside an if clause depending on button.selected. That's what the forState: argument is for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code here you also not change images respectively with your requirement.. i just think about your requirement and then post this code ..

```
-(IBAction)Bt1Click:(id)sender
{

    if (Bt1.selected)
    {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1image2.png"];
        [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        Bt1.selected = NO;

    }else{

        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1image1.png"];
        [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Bt1.selected = YES;
    }


    [self.searchBaar resignFirstResponder];
}
-(IBAction)Btn2Click:(id)sender
{

    if (Btn2.selected)
    {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn2image2.png"];
        [PeopButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        Btn2.selected = NO;

    }else{

        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn2image1.png"];
        [PeopButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Btn2.selected = YES;
    }


    [self.searchBaar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this for the first one and make the similar changes to second one:

-(IBAction)Bt1Click:(id)sender
    {

    if (Bt1.selected)
    {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1image2.png"];
        [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        Bt1.selected = NO;

    }else{

        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn2image1.png"];
        [foodButt setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Bt1.selected = YES;
    }


    [self.searchBaar resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the following:

```
if (Bt1.selected = YES)
```

which is not doing that you think its doing. The above code sets the selected property of Bt1 to YES, you want to do the following:

```
if (Bt1.selected == YES)
```

`=` assigns, while `==` compares, which is what you want here